# driver.get(url) not executing

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to automate some web scrapping in chrome

Previously I was trying it with a different method where the chrome used to open in guest mode and it was working, here is the previous method

`url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'#Example chrome = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())`

`chrome.get(url)`

But when I shifted the method, where the chrome would open logged in by default, it is showing problems, there is no error, but `driver.get(url)` is not working, infact any lines after `webdriver.Chrome...` are not working
Here is the code after changes

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default")

url = "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", options=options)
print("h")

driver.get(url)
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Put in in your post please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where you made a mistake.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", options=options)
```

you need to pass the `PATH` of the `chrome driver` Not the `chrome browser` installed path.

if you not sure path and your chrome browser compatibility then use below code.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
```